# Import module in typescript file gives error "cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, visual-studio-code

I am trying to import globally install gulp module, but I am getting error **"cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided"** in visual studio code.

Where to set this **--module** flag?
[image]

Comment: [In `tsconfig.json`, the `compilerOptions` section.](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open up your `tsconfig.json` file and make sure you have `module` set

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

The list of possible values for module are:

- commonjs
- amd
- umd
- system

**NOTE** if you already have `module` set, you might need to reload the editor via the command pallet

Also of note `--module` is in reference to the command-line argument prior to the introduction of `tsconfig.json` where it is just named `module`

Comment: I keep having this with just one file, it is in the tsconfig under "files" and compilation will not give this error. Opening the ts file will red underscore the entire file with this error and ctrl+P `>Reloac Window` does not fix the problem. Other files do not have this. Tried restarting the IDE and rebooting the computer but it still shows the error (only in VS code not the compile output and only for that file)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a situation where the compiler output does not indicate an error but VS Code does.

Having the following tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "watch": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "removeComments": true,
        "outDir": "."
    },
"files": [
        "Filter",
        "util.ts"
        ]
}
```

The compiler had no errors and would compile both Filter.ts and util.ts but because the tsconfig.json did not have the `.ts` extension in Filter; when opening util.ts it would underline the entire file contents in red with the **"cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided"**

Fixed it by adding the `.ts` at the end.

After changing the tsconfig.json I reloaded ctrl + p => `>Reload Window`